# How do I import a .csv file from Go to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, csv, go

I am currently using Go Mongo-driver Library. Following the instructions, I am able to insert a BSON to my local database. However, my application requires me to store a .csv file. Is there a way I can insert a .csv file to the local database.

Below is a code of how I used the mongo-driver library to insert a bson.

```
func main() {
    log.Print("Starting the application...")
    /*
        Connecting to Local DB
    */
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, _ := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    collection := client.Database("GoMongo").Collection("Test")

    res, err := collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{{"name", "test"}, {"email", "astestdf@paypal.com"}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    id := res.InsertedID
    fmt.Print(id)

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/user", CreateUserEndPoint).Methods("POST")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

}
```

Comment: You can construct documents from CSV lines, and you can insert those. There is no "automatic" import. What problems do you have?

Comment: You can use command-line utility `mongoimport` to import csv data into MongoDB database. An alternative is to run the `mongoimport` as an OS command from the golang.